# How can I find out what places in Central Europre can be reached in a given time from a city by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, planning, central-europe

When traveling, I'm often interested in visiting the surrounding area. Unfortunately, map distance doesn't necessarily relate well to travel time, especially when considering public transport.

There is a question specifically asking about [travel from Oxford or Cambridge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19566/how-can-i-work-out-where-i-can-go-for-a-weekend-away-by-public-transport-starti), but that's not were I'm usually staying. Are there any more generic solutions, particularly for central Europe?

Comment: The answer to that Oxford and Cambridge question contains a link where you can order a custom map for 25 pounds.

Comment: @DJClayworth The custom map is UK only, though.

Comment: But why would you ever want one for anywhere else? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, as of now, no general solution for any places, particularly since public transport data is not always freely available, [which makes coding such an application difficult](http://stefanwehrmeyer.com/blog/2010/11/01/mapnificent/).

For places where public transport data is available, there are sites that let you do draw areas of what you can visit.

[Mapnificent](http://www.mapnificent.net/) has a decent number of cities from all over the world. Note that it may not have access to the complete public transport data (see e.g. @Gagravarr's comment).

[image]

[arrlee](http://www.arrlee.eu/en/index.html) works for Germany, Switzerland, and Austria only, and is able to provide overlays of points of interest. It "knows" all public transport stops in these countries, as far as I can tell, and is thus quite reliable.

[image]

Comment: I've just tried Mapnificent with Brisbane (Australia), and it seems to be missing large amounts of the public transport options! I fear it's not yet ready for prime time use, though it's a nice idea...

Comment: @Gagravarr: thanks for the feedback - I have only been able to check arrlee, and that works very well.